# How to store Excel sheet data in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, excel

I have a column that can accept only `.xls` sheet. And I want to know how how we can store from the uploaded file in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways based on how you plan to access it once it's there. Here are the recommended ways from Microsoft (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321686)

- SQL Server Data Transformation Services (DTS)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Integration Services (SSIS)
- SQL Server linked servers
- SQL Server distributed queries
- ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) and the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
- ADO and the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet 4.0

The techniques for each method are described in the article (or you can google them). If you just need to keep the file for download, you could just load the excel file into a VARBINARY column.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the database you will use, but generally binary files will be stored as BLOBs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

I recommend against doing this if you can avoid it though.